# Twitter Query including a list_id with tweepy python

Tags: api, search, twitter, tweepy

I have created a Twitter List by the following lines:

```py
    import tweepy
    
# name of the list
    name = "tweepy_list"
    
    client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret, access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret)
    l = client.create_list(name)
    id_l = l[0]['id']
```

Where id_l is the list id.

I have added users to the list by:

```py
    client.add_list_member(id_l, user_id)
```

Now, I want to build a search query by this code and I want to include the list of users I previously created by:

```py
    query = "{0} lang:es -is:retweet list:{1}:".format(topic, id_l)
    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query,
                                             tweet_fields = ["created_at", "text", "source"],
                                             user_fields = ["name", "username", "location", "verified", "description"],
                                             max_results = 10,
                                             expansions='author_id',
                                             user_auth=True
                                             )
```

But I am getting this error:

```
> BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
> There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid operator 'list'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product
```

Can tweepy or another package support this kind of query from Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Twitter documentation ([here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query#list)), the `list` operator is accessible only to the developpers with an elevated access. So the easiest solution would be to apply for a elevated access. You can also learn how to do that in the Twitter documentation ([here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api)).

On a side note: you are not using the value of the `id_l` variable in your query but litteraly the string `'id_l'`. Don't forget to format it too (or to use f-strings).

Comment: Thank you! I corrected the query in the question. I will check elevated access.

Comment: I already have the elevated access. I think that the operator list is not available in tweepy package. Do you know any other package or way to execute this kind of query?

Comment: @anitasp Tweepy has nothing to do with that, it just transmits the query to Twitter. You can try to remove the space between `list:` and the id.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but I am still receiving the error :  BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid operator 'list'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product

Comment: Since this is a new functionality, that could be a bug. Unless someone else answers your question here, I would suggest you to ask it in the official Twitter developpers forum [here](https://twittercommunity.com/).

Comment: I followed your advice and I wrote on the Twitter developers forum. Thank you.

Comment: @anitasp You haven't removed the space between the `list:` and the `{1}` in the snippet that you shared there.

Comment: I tried in my terminal, now I corrected that in the snippet.